# API do Google maps não é suportado pelo o android

Tags: mobile

Quando eu tento virtualizar o android para iniciar com o Google Maps dar esse erro:

won’t run without Google Play Services, which are not supported by your device.

Se alguem poder me ajudar , já estou 4 dias com meu projeto parado tentando revolver isso , e nada.

OBS: sou novo no android.

Comment: Implementas-te o play services no build?

Answer (score 0):

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tiago.mapas3"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    itemplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

```
stImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}